# How to run appCmd in PowerShell to add custom headers to the Default Web Site

Tags: powershell, iis-7, escaping, appcmd, p3p

Please help me figure out how to properly escape the arguments so they work when calling appcmd inside of powershell.

**My script looks like this:**

```
$defaultWebSite = "Default Web Site"
$appCmd = "C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"
$addHeaderP3P = "set config ""$defaultWebSite"" -section:system.webServer/httpProtocol /+""customHeaders.[name='P3P',value='policyRef=`\`"/w3c/p3p.xml`\`",CP=`\`"DSP COR NID OUR COM PRE`\`"']`""

Write-Output "Here's the argument string: " $addHeaderP3P



Write-Output "`nInvoke Result:"
Invoke-Expression "$appCmd $addHeaderP3P"


Write-Output "`n& Result:"
& $appCmd --%"$addHeaderP3P"
```

**The output is this when running inside powershell_ise:**

```
PS C:\Users\robert.bratton> D:\Junk\p3pheader.ps1
Here's the argument string: 
set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/httpProtocol /+"customHeaders.[name='P3P',value='policyRef=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\",CP=\"DSP COR NID OUR COM PRE\"']"

Invoke Result:
Failed to process input: The parameter 'COR' must begin with a / or - (HRESULT=80070057).


& Result:
Failed to process input: The parameter 'NID' must begin with a / or - (HRESULT=80070057).
```

**This works from the command line**

```
"C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/httpProtocol /+"customHeaders.[name='P3P',value='policyRef=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\",CP=\"DSP COR NID OUR COM PRE\"']"
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9):

Try it like this:

```
$env:defaultWebSite = "Default Web Site"
$appCmd = "C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"

& $appCmd --% set config "%defaultWebSite%" -section:system.webServer/httpProtocol /+customHeaders.[name='P3P',value='policyRef="/w3c/p3p.xml",CP="DSP COR NID OUR COM PRE"']
```

If you use any variables after the `--%` the have to be environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I get an error about a missing close quote.

The string starting:
At line:4 char:180
+ & $appCmd --% set config "%defaultWebSite%" -section:system.webServer/httpProtocol /+""customHeaders.[name='P3P',value='policyRef=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\",CP=\"DSP COR NID OUR COM PRE\"'] <<<< "
is missing the terminator: ".
At line:4 char:181

Comment: I copied everything from `-section` to the end from the example you listed above as working.  However you may have made changes to make that work from PowerShell.  At the point you specify --% PowerShell parses more like cmd.exe.  Let me take a crack to getting rid of the PowerShell workarounds.